# pandas, apply string operation to column should be string type, but has missing values (np.nan)

Tags: python, string, pandas, missing-data

I have a pandas dataframe df, one of df's column "names" is a Series of strings, where I use numpy.nan for missing values.

When I try to truncate each string in that column based on certain condition:

```
trunc = lambda s: s[:-10] if cond1 else s
df.names = df.names.apply(trunc)
```

The trunc( numpy.nan) is giving me an error. **type 'float' is not iterable.**

What is the easiest way to get the job done? 
One solution I can think of is to write trunc() function more robustly, that can handles numpy.nan as input. Is it good practice to set missing string value to numpy.nan?

Thanks

Comment: documentation on the string methods: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.names` is a `pd.Series`, and [`pd.Series` have string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) accessible through its `str` attribute:

```
df.loc[cond1, 'names'] = df.loc[cond1, 'names'].str.slice(None, -10)
```

This `str.slice` method intelligently ignores NaN.

---

For example:

```
In [28]: df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['abcdefghij', np.nan, 'klmnopqrst', np.nan]})

In [29]: df
Out[29]: 
        names
0  abcdefghij
1         NaN
2  klmnopqrst
3         NaN

[4 rows x 1 columns]

In [30]: cond1 = [True, False, False, True]

In [31]: df.loc[cond1, 'names'] = df.loc[cond1, 'names'].str.slice(None, -10)

In [32]: df
Out[32]: 
        names
0            
1         NaN
2  klmnopqrst
3         NaN

[4 rows x 1 columns]
```